# Find the sign of the following integral: $\int_{0}^{2\pi}{\sin x\over x}$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Am I required to know if it is positive or negative? This expression is not really integrable, not within the boundaries of the course at least. I tried comparing it to other integrals but I get zero all the time. I am not sure I have fully understood what I should do. I would really appreciate any help in this.

An attempt using an advice here: $\sin x$ between $0$ to $\pi$ equals $-\sin x$ between $\pi $ to $2\pi$. Since we are looking at $\sin x\over x$, $\int_{\pi}^{2\pi}{\sin x\over x}$ might be negative, but still is smaller than $\int_{0}^{\pi}{\sin x\over x}$, therefore, the sign is +1. Is that sufficient?

Comment: It's a fine bounded and continuous function, so the integral exists. It helps to split it up at $\pi$.

Comment: split the integral at $\pi$ argue that the part  with boundarys $[\pi ,2\pi]$ is smaller in absolute value then the part with boundarys $[0, \pi]$

Comment: I don't know how to use the "absolute value" argument, but I edited my answer. How is it? Actually it is supposed to be a question in a test of a strict professor, and it couldn't be that it is that simple. Is there any hard work needs to be done that I missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function

Look at the graph and compare the intervals $x \in [0,\pi]$ and $[\pi,2\pi]$: The sign is clearly positive.

You can just argue

$$\forall x \in [0,\pi] \ : \ \ \ \frac{\sin(t)}{t} > -\frac{\sin(t+\pi)}{t + \pi} = \frac{\sin(t)}{t + \pi}$$

which yields that the first half of your integral has greater magnitude than the second half.

Answer (score 8):

It is positive:
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\sin x}{x}\,dx = \int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin x}{x}\,dx+\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{-\sin(x)}{x+\pi}\,dx = \pi\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin x}{x(x+\pi)}\,dx.$$

Comment: I didn't understand the last equality. Is that a specific identity? 
I would really help if you elaborated.

Comment: @Meitar: $$\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x+\pi}=\frac{\pi}{x(x+\pi)}.$$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Can you please explain why is $\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin x}{x(x+\pi)}\,dx$ is strictly positive?

Comment: @NegligibleSenescence: because the integrand function is non-negative over $(0,\pi)$ and lower-bounded by a positive constant in a large neighbourhood of $\frac{\pi}{2}$.